# Boost locale normalize strips characters but no accents

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-locale

I am trying to strip accents from a string using the boost local library.

The normalize function removes the entire character with the accent, i only want to remove the accent.

è -> e for example

Here is my code

```
std::string hello(u8"élève");
boost::locale::generator gen;
std::string str = boost::locale::normalize(hello,boost::locale::norm_nfd,gen(""));
```

Desired ouput : eleve

My Output : lve

Help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not what normalize does. With `nfd` it does "canonical decomposition". You need to THEN remove the combining character code points.

**UPDATE** Adding a loose implementation gleaning from [the utf8 tables](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?number=1024&utf8=0x) that most combining character appear to lead with 0xcc or 0xcd:

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VyIhKSmJyLicmx4e)**

```
// also liable to strip some greek characters that lead with 0xcd
template <typename Str>
static Str try_strip_diacritics(
    Str const& input,
    std::locale const& loc = std::locale())
{
    using Ch = typename Str::value_type;
    using T = boost::locale::utf::utf_traits<Ch>;

    auto tmp = boost::locale::normalize(
                input, boost::locale::norm_nfd, loc);

    auto f = tmp.begin(), l = tmp.end(), out = f;

    while (f!=l) {
        switch(*f) {
            case '\xcc':
            case '\xcd': // TODO find more
                T::decode(f, l);
                break; // skip
            default:
                out = T::encode(T::decode(f, l), out);
                break;
        }
    }
    tmp.erase(out, l);
    return tmp;
}
```

Prints (on my box!):

```
Before: "élève"  0xc3 0xa9 0x6c 0xc3 0xa8 0x76 0x65
all-in-one: "eleve"  0x65 0x6c 0x65 0x76 0x65
```

---

Older answer text/analysis:

```
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

static void dump(std::string const& s) {
    std::cout << std::hex << std::showbase << std::setfill('0');
    for (uint8_t ch : s)
        std::cout << " " << std::setw(4) << int(ch);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    boost::locale::generator gen;

    std::string const pupil(u8"élève");

    std::string const str =
        boost::locale::normalize(
            pupil,
            boost::locale::norm_nfd,
            gen(""));

    std::cout << "Before: "; dump(pupil);
    std::cout << "After:  "; dump(str);
}
```

Prints, on my box:

```
Before:  0xc3 0xa9 0x6c 0xc3 0xa8 0x76 0x65
After:   0x65 0xcc 0x81 0x6c 0x65 0xcc 0x80 0x76 0x65
```

> However, on Coliru it [makes no difference](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4a6f1fc9eef0549). This indicates that it depends on the available/system locales.

The docs say: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/libs/locale/doc/html/conversions.html#conversions_normalization

> Unicode normalization is the process of converting strings to a
> standard form, suitable for text processing and comparison. For
> example, character "ü" can be represented by a single code point or a
> combination of the character "u" and the diaeresis "¨". Normalization
> is an important part of Unicode text processing.
>
> Unicode defines four normalization forms. Each specific form is
> selected by a flag passed to normalize function:
>
> - NFD - Canonical decomposition - `boost::locale::norm_nfd`
> - NFC - Canonical decomposition followed by canonical composition - boost::locale::norm_nfc or `boost::locale::norm_default`
> - NFKD - Compatibility decomposition - `boost::locale::norm_nfkd`
> - NFKC - Compatibility decomposition followed by canonical composition - `boost::locale::norm_nfkc`
>
> For more details on normalization forms, read [this article][1].

### What you could do

It seems that you MIGHT get some way by doing the *Decomposition* only (so NFD) and then removing any code-points that aren't alpha.

<strike>This is cheating, because it assumes all code-points are single-unit, which is not generically true, but for the sample it does work:</strike>

See improved version above which does iterate over code-points instead of bytes.

Comment: I just found a more accurate way to approximate this behaviour using decomposed normal form and UTF traits from the locale library, adding

Comment: Added improved version which does iterate over code-points instead of byte